# Getting "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" when compiling cmake code

Tags: c++, macos, boost, cmake, ros

I'm trying to compile a ROS package which uses Boost. The code compiles just fine on Linux, but on OS X I'm getting the error

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I installed Boost through brew and it seems that it is installed in 64bit (my system is also 64bit - OS X 10.9), as running

```
file libboost_atomic-mt.dylib
```

outputs

```
libboost_atomic-mt.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

In the CMakeFiles.txt, I've tried nearly everything in terms of compile and link flags, having tried -stdlib both as libc++ and as libstdc++, as well as -mmacosx-version-min as everything from 10.5 to 10.9. For instance, right now I have:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9")
```

Furthermore, building with -m64 produces the same errors, and building with -m32 produces the same errors except that it says "... architecture i136".

The following paste bins contain my CMakefiles.txt and the compiling errors, respectively:

http://pastebin.com/0MD8T916 - CMakeFiles.txt

http://pastebin.com/v3vk9i2r - Errors

I'm running out of ideas for fixing this issue...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It seems to me that it's not finding something inside ros. Should you add ros to target_link_libraries() or is it handled as part of MADP_LIBRARIES?

Comment: It isn't. Adding ROS to target_link_libraries() seems to have worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, good to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

You did not actually add/link the boost libraries inside your project.

```
set(BOOST_COMPONENTS
    unit_test_framework
    program_options
    thread) # And other components you need

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) # Easier to deploy elsewhere
set(BOOST_ROOT /usr/local/opt/boost) # Useful for boost from brew
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /usr/local/opt/boost/lib64)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${BOOST_COMPONENTS})

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(<your target> ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and will be leaving it in, but it didn't really solve the problem, I still get the exact same output..